# Is initial state needed when coding a GUI with druid?

Tags: rust, druid-rs

I guess I'm not completely sure what initial state means in Druid, or if it is even needed at all.

```
AppLauncher::with_window(main_window)
    .log_to_console()
    .launch(initial_state)
    .expect("Failed to launch application");
```

Do I have to launch initial state?

Ive tried a few things but they've lead to errors.

Comment: "Ive tried a few things but they've lead to errors." isn't very helpful for us. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried and what errors that led to.

Comment: All the examples I saw show that you can pass `0` as a state. Have you tried that? `.launch(0)`?

Comment: The application state is a parameter that Druid passes along to all the callbacks so that your UI can display and change it. Its actual type and value depend on your application. `initial_state` is the value it should have when your application starts, and that depends on your application, so _we_ can't know what to put.

Comment: And yes, you need to call `launch` since that's the function that actually causes your UI to run…